# Matlab cell array equivalent in java

Tags: java

I would like to implement cell arrays (Matlab) in java. Since i am new to java programming i am not sure what could be used in java similar to cell arrays.

Can you please suggest me what can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java have [arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) too. If you are looking for cell arrays (matrices type), the key word to use is multi dimensional arrays.

Comment: Thanks...In multidimensional array is it possible to store arrays in each cell?

Comment: Yes, you can choose array as a type. So that you can store an array in place of element.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [arrays](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/) which are objects in java.
You can create an array in java as below:-

```
 int[] array=new int[10];
```

Above code will create an array of integers of size 10.

Two-dimensional arrays, called matrices (singular:  matrix).  A matrix resembles a table with rows and columns.

```
int [ ] [ ] marks = new int [ 4 ] [ 5 ] ;
```

[image]

Above code int [ 4 ] [ 5 ] indicates that there will be four arrays of ints in the array marks, with 5 ints in each array of ints.